# Legendre Polynomials proving a relation using Rodrigue's Formula

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential, legendre-polynomials, legendre-functions

I have been trying to prove the relation$\left (P'_n(1)=\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)\right )$ and have proved it directly from the Legendre differential equation as $P_n(x)${the Legendre polynomial} is the solution of the Legendre differential equation, given as $$(1-x^2)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-2x\frac{dy}{dx}+n(n+1)y=0\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:...(1)$$and we can write equation $(1)$ as $$(1-x^2)P''_n(x)-2xP'_n(x)+n(n+1)P_n(x)\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:...(2)$$and then putting $x=1$ in $(2)$, we get $$0\:-\:2P'_n(1)\:+\: n(n+1)P_n(1)=0\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:...(3)$$ $$\implies 2P'_n(1)=n(n+1)\:.(1)\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:[as P_n(1)=1]$$ $$\implies P'_n(1)=\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:$$where $P'_n(x)$ and $P''_n(x)$ are first order and second order derivative of Legendre polynomial respectively.

But my question is *how can we prove the same relation by using the* **Rodrigues's Formula** which is given as follows $$P_n(x)=\frac{1}{2^n.n!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-1)^n$$ I have been trying to solve the relation by using **Rodrigues's Formula** but I don't have any idea how to solve it. Please help.

**Thanks beforehand :)**

Comment: Essentially, you'd have to calculate $\displaystyle\frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}}(x^2-1)^n=\frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}}(x-1)^n\,(x+1)^n$ at $x=1$. Do you know https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule? It looks like a lot of summands at first glance, but most of them are $0$ for $x=1$.

Comment: The correct spelling is "Rodrigues's".

Comment: @K.defaoite Sorry I have mistaken...you are right.

Comment: @ProfessorVector I don't have any idea about the general Leibnitz rule...can you explain in detail...how can I use that to get my answer?...Is there any easy process to approach the same? As I have checked the link but that information is far beyond my approach.